# Run X11 Server (VcXsrv) from Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, x11, wsl-2

I would like to set up an X11 Server so that I can run graphical Linux applications using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL 2).  I have tried following the instructions on [this site](https://medium.com/@elecming/the-ultimate-emacs-hacking-tutorial-in-windows-10-wsl-2-2fc4e9a899b0).

The command

```
choco install vcxsrv
```

completed successfully.  But I cannot see how to start XLaunch (VcXsrv).

I already have Cygwin/X X Server installed on my machine and I am still able to launch that successfully.  But when I try the following command,

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> vcxsrv
```

I get the following error message,

```
vcxsrv : The term 'vcxsrv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

I have spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out how to start XLaunch (VcXsrv) without any success.

Comment: This really isn't a programming question, however - I suggest you follow the [instructions found here](https://sourceforge.net/p/vcxsrv/wiki/Using%20VcXsrv%20Windows%20X%20Server/). I believe `Xlaunch.exe -run config.xlaunch` might be the command you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try to look on default folder installation:

"C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\xlaunch.exe"

Comment: Thanks.  Your suggestion did resolve the issue for me.  I was confused because Chocolatey previously installed a program in `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib`.  It would be nice if the answer above could be expanded a bit.  E.g. from Powershell are there commands that would tell me what the default install paths for Chocolately are?  How does the default install path get overwritten in the install script `chocolateyinstall.ps1`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to run VcXsrv

```
xfsettingsd --sm-client-disable; xfce4-panel --sm-client-disable --disable-wm-check &
```

or

```
C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\xlaunch.exe
```

Refer the following link to understand VcXsrv installation and it's usage,

[Running WSL GUI Apps on Windows 10](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/running-wsl-gui-apps-on-windows-10/ba-p/1493242)

Comment: xlaunch.exe is fine. But xfce4-panel assumes other software has been installed (and configured to launch vcxsrv) -- and that's probably not going to be useful (xfce4 is not included with the copy of vcxsrv which I am looking at).